# Dynamics in Gephi

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, gephi

I want to do a social network analysis graph with some dynamics. The dynamics that I would like is on certain dates I want nodes to change colours and labels but I would like the links to stay the same. There are a few packages in R that do social network analysis such as `igraph`, `igraph0`, `network` and `sna` but these packages are quite limited in terms of visualisations.

I have also tried Gephi and have had some success in terms of dynamics where I can get node/links to appear/disappear at certain time points. (Can give the code for this if people want). But in terms of the dynamics I would like, as mentioned in the above paragraph, I have read online that at the moment gephi cannot do such dynamics.

My question is therefore: will there be a gephi version that will do such dynamics or what is the best open source social networking analysis visualisation software that will do such dynamics?

Cheers in advance

P.S. I wasn't to sure what to tag the question under so I went with gephi and R. Please correct me if there is a better tag that I should have used.

Comment: If it is just about visualization and not computation of properties of networks, then you can just use igraph and add attributes to vertices and edged that define when they are present in the network, and hide the vertices/edges that are not there at a particular time point. To hide a vertex, set its shape to "none", to hide an edge, set its width to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamics that you are describing seems to be very simple, but if you want to have the ability to implement any complex dynamics over your graph, and at the same time produce a nice visualization, a good solution for your problem is to use the Gephi Graph Streaming plugin ( https://gephi.org/plugins/graph-streaming/ ), plus some script in your favorite scripting language.

Using this plugin, you transform your Gephi process in a visualization endpoint that receives REST requests to update the graph, and you can implement your dynamic process using any programming language that can send HTTP requests.

Take a look at some examples using Python as scripting language at this repository:
https://github.com/panisson/pygephi_graphstreaming/.
The square.py example is very simple, but it shows the ability to add and remove nodes from a graph, visualizing it in Gephi. Moreover, while you are updating the graph, you can also use Gephi to run analysis and layouts in real time.

Answer (score 0):

For R, you might want to check out the packages [networkDynamic](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/networkDynamic/index.html)  and [ndtv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ndtv/index.html) packages for visualizing and animating dynamic network data